# tkinter grid method not properly placing the button

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to place a tkinter `Button` widget at specific coordinates within a window, but the button seems to ignore the coordinates and is always places at the top left corner of my window.

This is the code I have been running:

```
import tkinter as ter

root = ter.Tk()

root.minsize(500,500)

im = ter.PhotoImage(height=1, width=1)

my_button = ter.Button(root, height=1, width=1, image=im, bg="black")
my_button.grid(row=250, column=250)

root.mainloop()
```

This is the result:

[image: screenshot of result]

You can see that the button is placed at (0,0) even though I have mentioned (250,250) as its coordinates. I am not sure if I have a bug in my machine. How can I achieve desired behaviour of the button widget?

Comment: Use `.place(x=..., y=...)` instead of using `.grid(...)`. The `grid` method is for laying out multiple widgets correctly, relative to each other, without giving exact coordinates. The `place` method is used to specify exact coordinates.

Comment: Also, it is more common to use `import tkinter as tk`, not `ter`.

Comment: `.grid()` uses the relative position of other widgets to create a grid (and therefore positions). You only have one widget, so no matter what, it will be placed in the top left corner.

Comment: Empty grid cells dont take any space by default.

Comment: @Lecdi A lot of tutorials that I have been following used `.grid()` method to place widgets, although now I realise they were all working with multiple widgets. Thanks for the answer! Also, I try to keep names of the variables distinct. It feels awkward for me to type `tk.Tk()`

Comment: I think what you need is `padx` and `pady`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the `.grid(row=x,column=x)` method, yet there are no other columns/rows, your image will be put in the first (zeroeth) row and in the first (zeroeth) column. Because of that, either fill the other columns with blanks by saying:

```
blank = Label(root,text = " ")
blank.grid(row=0,column=0)
blank.grid(row=1,column=1)
```

etc.

Or you could add padx,pady,idapx,ipady settings to your image.

Another solution would be trying to use the `.place()` method which is described [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/tk_place.htm)

EDIT: You can also try placing a bunch of white images to fill in the grids if you want to

Comment: You don't have to actually put anything in all the unused positions, like a `Label` or image, you can instead just configure the rows and columns themselves — see my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73070985/355230).

Comment: I think `.place()` method capture the utility I want to achieve perfectly. Filling the window with empty strings feels rather sketchy. But yeah, filling the window with constant sized images might be clever for the project that I am trying to get done. Thanks for your insight!

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out in comments, rows and columns with nothing in them take up no space, and the only gridded widget you have is a custom Button at position `row=250, column=250`.

You can change that and make tkinter consider even empty rows and columns by configuring their relative "weights" using the `rowconfigure()` and `columnconfigure()` methods as shown below. Here's some [documentation](https://tkdocs.com/shipman/grid-config.html).

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

root.minsize(500,500)

# Specify minimum grid row and column sizes for a grid of given dimensions.
height, width = 250, 250
for column in range(width):
    root.columnconfigure(column, weight=1)

for row in range(height):
    root.rowconfigure(row, weight=1)

im = tk.PhotoImage(height=1, width=1)

my_button = tk.Button(root, height=1, width=1, image=im, bg="black")
my_button.grid(row=250, column=250)

root.mainloop()
```

If you make the changes shown above to your script, you should get something like what is shown below where the `Button` is not being displayed in the lower right corner. I'm not sure if that is what you want because you have not indicated what the maximum grid positions you intend to use are — but you can rectify that by changing the values assigned to the `width` and `height` variables in the code above.

Result:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: That is a very elegent solution, but it seems that it pushes the button to the coordinates (500,500) and it would become very hard for me to determine the number of rows and columns that need to be given 'weight' so that the button lands up at the exact coordinates that I desire (but perhaps it might be 125 rows and columns?) the `.place()` methods seems to work perfectly. Thanks for your insight!

Answer (score 0):

I give two options, either `place()` or `pack()`.Actually, both are the same positions at specific coordinates.

Either comment out  or comment in line 10 or line 11.

Same code as your:

```
import tkinter as ter

root = ter.Tk()

root.minsize(500,500)

im = ter.PhotoImage(height=1, width=1)

my_button = ter.Button(root, height=1, width=1, image=im, bg="black")
#my_button.pack(side=ter.LEFT, padx=250, pady=250)
my_button.place(x=250, y=250)
root.mainloop()
```

Screenshot:

[image]